# Can't get jquery to removeClass from specific div on link click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, removeclass

I have been struggling to figure out what I am doing wrong here with such a simple task. Essentially what I am trying to accomplish is when a user clicks a link, say "edit", it should removeClass "hidden" from a div on that screen so it will display. This isn't working, however. When I click the link, nothing happens.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
<a href="#edit">Edit</a>

<div id="editAccount" class="hidden">
    <p>Content!</p>
</div>

$("edit a").click(function() {
     $("#editAccount").removeClass("hidden");
 });
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `$("edit a")` is not a valid selector, maybe `$(".edit a")` or `$("#edit a")` or `$("a[href='#edit']")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your selector is wrong, use this one:

```
$("a[href='#edit']").click(function() {
    $("#editAccount").removeClass("hidden");
});
```

Comment: I tried this as well as just trying $("#edit") and assigning the "<a href>" an id="#edit" it just doesn't seem to have any affect. Jquery is properly being called on the page too because other jquery functions seem to be working just fine.

Comment: @crescentfresh Don't use `#` in `id` attribute, then it should work with `$('#edit')`, also make sure the id is unique on the page

Comment: @Tushar sorry I didn't mean id=#, that was an accident. id is unique, i've even made an arbitrary id just to make sure.

Comment: @Tushar ugh, you were on the right track! I had id="#editAccount" in the div id code. Thanks for your help. I'm an idiot. haha.

Comment: @crescentfresh Glad to help :)